# mouseDown not firing properly on NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, mouseevent

I tried implementing the second answer posted in this post [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684166/which-delegate-method-should-i-use-to-respond-to-clicks-on-an-nstextfield#684166) I have the desire as the person asking the question however my `mouseDown` is not working/registering. Here is what I have.

1. AppDelegate.h
2. AppDelegate.m
3. MouseDownTextField.h
4. MouseDownTextField.m

and there relavent content:

1. AppDelegate.h

   ```
   #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
   #import "MouseDownTextField.h"
   @interface AppDelegate : NSObject <MouseDownTextFieldDelegate> {
   NSWindow *window;
   IBOutlet NSMenu *statusMenu;
   NSStatusItem *statusItem;
   NSMutableArray *selector;
   NSMutableArray *display;
   NSTimer *timer;
   MouseDownTextField *quoteHolder; }
   @property IBOutlet MouseDownTextField *quoteHolder;
   @end
   ```
2. AppDelegate.m

   ```
   - (void)displayString:(NSString *)title {
     NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(50, 0, 200, 17);
     quoteHolder = [[MouseDownTextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
     [[self quoteHolder] setDelegate:self];
     [quoteHolder setStringValue:title];
     [quoteHolder setTextColor:[NSColor blueColor]];
     [test addSubview:quoteHolder];
     [statusItem setView:test]; }
     -(void)mouseDownTextFieldClicked:(MouseDownTextField *)textField {
        NSLog(@"Clicked");}
   ```
3. MouseDownTextField.h

   ```
   #import <Appkit/Appkit.h>
   @class MouseDownTextField;

   @protocol MouseDownTextFieldDelegate <NSTextFieldDelegate>
   -(void) mouseDownTextFieldClicked:(MouseDownTextField *)textField;
   @end

   @interface MouseDownTextField: NSTextField {
   }
   @property(assign) id<MouseDownTextFieldDelegate> delegate;
   @end
   ```
4. MouseDownTextField.m

   ```
   #import "MouseDownTextField.h"
   @implementation MouseDownTextField
    -(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {
   [self.delegate mouseDownTextFieldClicked:self]; }
   -(void)setDelegate:(id<MouseDownTextFieldDelegate>)delegate {
   [super setDelegate:delegate]; }
   -(id)delegate {
   return [super delegate]; }
   @end
   ```

Thoughts on what could be wrong or what i have done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating quoteHolder in IB, you should remove the following line of code and you should be fine.

```
quoteHolder = [[MouseDownTextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

The result of reassigning the `NSTextField` is that the one you are clicking is no longer the one registered with the delegate.  No need to add it as a `subview` either, it's already been added to the view hierarchy in IB.

Also, make sure in IB, under Accessibility, "User Interaction Enabled" is checked for the `NSTextField`.

As for the follow up quesion, how could you have multiple of these?

If you were adding multiple `NSTextField` instances in IB, each would be referenced as a @property just as you did with quoteHolder. The linkage is done in IB like this [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3826990/1354100).

These could all have the same delegate.  When `mouseDownTextFieldClicked:` is pressed you could interrogate the `NSTextField` for a unique id which could be assigned in IB as well.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry about the delay, but dosent this link them `[[self quoteHolder] setDelegate:self];` after I create it?

Comment: And if thats the case, lets say I am creating multipul of these, how would i do that?

Comment: @Mr.S The text field you have in your xib is a real object, just like the one you create with `alloc`/`initWithFrame:`, and it's already pointed to by the `IBOutlet` variable `quoteHolder`. Don't reassign that variable in `displayString`; just use the value that's already assigned when the xib is loaded.

Comment: @Mr.SirKingOsman if you were adding multiple `UITextField` instances in IB, each would be referenced as a @property just as you did with quoteHolder.  The linkage is done in IB like this [linked answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3826990/1354100).