# Why won't my IBOutlets show up in my list of Outlets in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, iboutlet

I basically have code that reflects the answer from  [Connect a UILabel in Interface Builder and XCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826906/connect-a-uilabel-in-interface-builder-and-xcode).

In one view controller I have several UILabels whose text is set by some other methods I have written in viewDidLoad.  This has worked fine, but today I tried adding a couple more labels in the same fashion and I can't get their references to show up in the Outlets list in Interface builder.  How does identical code not work in the same view controller?

Answer (score 3):

1) Make sure you have written the IBOutlet property correctly,

[image]

2) **File's Owner** Custom Class of Your .xib should be your **ViewController** class

[image]

3) If you right click on the File's Owner which is listed under Placeholders, The **IBOutlet**  myLabel should be there,

[image]

4) And make sure you have connected the IBOutlet to your UILabel.

[image]

5) Set the text of the Label from your **viewDidLoad** method,

[image]